# How to get the cell value from an HTML table's second last row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of the **first cell** in the **second last row** of my table. The rows are created dynamically (in a Django project) and I am using the each addition of a row as the trigger to get the cell value for further processing.

To get the last row, first cell value, I could use:

`var first_bull = $('#my_table tr:last').find('td:first').text();`

I can construct a hash on the fly and get the value but what I am trying to do is using a simpler, one line code that could do the job, if that is possible.

How do I get the first cell's value of the second last row? I used `.prev()` but drawing blank though there is value available in the cell.

Also in the code above, `.val()` doesn't work, whereas the following works:

`varText = $('#id_my_txt').val();`

Why?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$('#id_my_txt').val()` works because `$('#id_my_txt')` is input or textarea element.

To get value of input present in second last row and first column, you should try:

```
$('#my_table tr:last').prev().find('td').eq(0).find('input').val()
// To get cell text present inside second last cell:
$('#my_table tr:last').prev().find('td').eq(0).text()
```

Comment: `text()` returns only plain text (not any tags or HTML structure). eg. `<div><p>A</p></div>` then `$("div").text()` will return only `A`(plain text). And `$("div").html()` will return `<p>A</p>` (html structure). You can use `.html()` to get HTML structure in string